# 415 Unsupported Media Type issue in my Controller [C#]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, controller

I created an endpoint so Google can have access to some database pictures. This is how my Endpoint looks like.

```
      [HttpGet]
      [Route("MiniPicture")]
      [Produces("image/png")]
      public async Task<IActionResult> GetPictureAsync(Selector selector)
      {

        var resultFromService = await _xxx.GetPicturefromDB(selector, "de3-ae21a5a7b1fd");

        var reponseAsByte = resultFromService.Results[0].Result.PictureAsByteArray;

        if (reponseAsByte != null)
        {
          var resp = File(reponseAsByte, "image/png");
          return resp;
        }
        return Ok(resultFromService.Results.FirstOrDefault());
      }
```

The above MiniPicture is in my Google Controller. So my Get request looks like this (I´m sending my bearer in Query because I have to Authenticate the user since I'm working with identity Server 4... but the authentication works fine.. )

```
http://xxx/ccc/fff/v1/google/MiniPicture?ProductId=2755&Bearer=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1N...
```

I have tried this with my Google Action and Postman and I become the following error:

> ```
> {
>     "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13",
>     "title": "Unsupported Media Type",
>     "status": 415,
>     "traceId": "|872be489-42f772a16832ade1."
> }
> ```

It would be very helpful if you can tell me what should I check:s This error is driving me **nuts**!

Answer (score 0):

so based on what I found about HTTP status 415

> The HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type client error response code
> indicates that the server refuses to accept the request because the
> payload format is in an unsupported format.

I think that you need to specify what kind of input this endpoint expects.
You only stated what it will produce, so try to add an information of what it's expecting.

Also, why Selector? I would expect a numeric data type in that parameter, since you fed it an ID :))

Answer (score 0):

This is an example prepared based on your controller code, and it works perfectly:

```
[HttpGet]
[Produces("image/png")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPictureAsync()
{   
    //var resultFromService = await _xxx.GetPicturefromDB(selector, "de3-ae21a5a7b1fd");

    //var reponseAsByte = resultFromService.Results[0].Result.PictureAsByteArray;
  
    var reponseAsByte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\\REPOS\\Test.png");       

    if (reponseAsByte != null)
    {
        var resp = File(reponseAsByte, "image/png");
        return resp;
    }

    return Ok(reponseAsByte);
}
```

**The missed parts** of the example code are

```
    var resultFromService = await _xxx.GetPicturefromDB(selector, "de3-ae21a5a7b1fd");
```

and

```
    var reponseAsByte = resultFromService.Results[0].Result.PictureAsByteArray;
```

And **that means** the **byte array** is not generated in a proper way so your problem either in `GetPicturefromDB` method or in `PictureAsByteArray` method.

**For** the `PictureAsByteArray` you can try something like this:

```
//using System;
//using System.IO;
//using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

private byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return null;

        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        bf.Serialize(ms, obj);

        return ms.ToArray();
    }
```

**While** for `GetPicturefromDB`, you need to be sure it returns a healthy result, otherwise you need to post the code to have an in-depth look at it.